# Timeline of learning the parts of the written and oral Torahs

Tags: sources-mekorot, kabbalat-hatorah

As we follow the rule that the Torah is not chronological (אין מוקדם ומאוחר בתורה), I'm very confused about the order of receiving different parts of the Torah in the 40 years from the Exodus to the entering to the Promised Land.

We know that some Parshios/Laws were given in Egypt (החודש הזה לכם or קרבן פסח) some before Matan Torah (חוקים במרה) some at Mt. Sinai (the 10 commandments) and some later up until the final days of Moses.

Did somebody make a clear timeline of what parts of the written and the oral Torah were learned when?

My question focuses on the actual learning the parts of the Torah, not about when did Moses write the scroll.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82783/170