# Did the Israelites know the future?

Tags: history, kabbalat-hatorah, latid-lavo-future

The Torah was revealed to Israel at a certain point in time, and recounts many significant events that happened after that point.  When the Torah was revealed, did the Israelites know about these future events before they occurred?  In particular, did Moses know?  If so, were his various reactions just staged?

Can we say that "revelation of the Torah" only includes teachings and commandments, but not future events?  Not really, because the Gemara says God dictated the entire Torah *text* to Moses, and Moses even wrote about his own death with tears, not ink, then Joshua rewrote these parts with ink. [Bava Batra 15a]

Who knew what and when did they know it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When Did Moses Receive the Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82783/when-did-moses-receive-the-torah)

Comment: Not really.  It doesn't clearly explain who knew what when.  The Sources clearly say Moses taught Torah to the people.  What was he teaching them?  Just commandments?

Comment: Moses only wrote the full text right before he died. What he received on Mt. Sinai was the commandments.